# java script canvas clock rotate number in correct position

Tags: javascript, canvas, clock

clock digit display incorrect position how to rotate correct position .
I think does not colculate correct angle of each digit.

these lines of code have error and here is calculate angle of each digit

any one finde the error and how to solve this

and how to calculate analog clock wise digit

```
for (var n = 1; n <=12; n++) {  
        var theta = (n - 12) * (Math.PI * 2) / 12;
        var x = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.sin(theta);  
        ctx.fillText(n, x, y);  
        ctx.rotate(theta); 
    }
```

[clock image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M3Dd.png)

clock clocke

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script>


function init(){

  clock();
  setInterval(clock, 1000);
}
function toRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function clock(){  

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var clockRadius = 110;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,150,150);
  ctx.translate(75,75);
  ctx.scale(0.4,0.4);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.lineCap = "round"; 
 ctx.font = '22px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  var now = new Date($("#datetime").val());
  //alert(now);
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var hr  = now.getHours();
  hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr; 

   for (var n = 1; n <=12; n++) {  
        var theta = (n - 12) * (Math.PI * 2) / 12;
        var x = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.sin(theta);  
        ctx.fillText(n, x, y);  
        ctx.rotate(theta ); 
    }

  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.save();
  for (var i=0; i < 12; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/6);
    ctx.moveTo(100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(120,0);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.restore();

  // Minute marks
  ctx.save();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  for (i=0;i<60;i++){
    if (i%5!=0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(117,0);
      ctx.lineTo(120,0);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/30);
  }
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";

  // write Hours

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#4D514E";
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate( hr*(Math.PI/6) + (Math.PI/360)*min + (Math.PI/21600)*sec )
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20,0);
  ctx.lineTo(80,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  // write Minutes
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate( (Math.PI/30)*min + (Math.PI/1800)*sec )
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-28,0);
  ctx.lineTo(110,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  // Write seconds
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI/30);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 6;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-30,0);
  ctx.lineTo(110,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
  ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#494545';
  ctx.arc(0,0,142,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();
} init(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rotate the whole context in the line 7 of the clock function.

```
function clock(){  

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var clockRadius = 110;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,150,150);
  ctx.translate(75,75);
  ctx.scale(0.4,0.4);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2); // <-- remove this
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ...
```

You need to remove that. Instead of doing that you can just rotate when drawing the arms.

```
// write Hours
ctx.rotate( -Math.PI/2 + hr*(Math.PI/6) + (Math.PI/360)*min + (Math.PI/21600)*sec )

// write Minutes
ctx.rotate( -Math.PI/2 + (Math.PI/30)*min + (Math.PI/1800)*sec )

// Write seconds
ctx.rotate( -Math.PI/2 + sec * Math.PI/30);
```

(and the codes for drawing digits will need a minor fix)

```
var theta = (n - 3) * (Math.PI * 2) / 12;
```

```js
function init(){

  clock();
  setInterval(clock, 1000);
}
function toRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function clock(){  

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var clockRadius = 110;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,150,150);
  ctx.translate(75,75);
  ctx.scale(0.4,0.4);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.lineCap = "round"; 
 ctx.font = '22px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  var now = new Date('2000/1/1 ' + $("#datetime").val());
  //alert(now);
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var hr  = now.getHours();
  hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr; 

   for (var n = 1; n <=12; n++) {  
        var theta = (n - 3) * (Math.PI * 2) / 12;
        var x = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = clockRadius * 0.7 * Math.sin(theta);  
        ctx.fillText(n, x, y);  
    }

  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.save();
  for (var i=0; i < 12; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/6);
    ctx.moveTo(100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(120,0);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.restore();

  // Minute marks
  ctx.save();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  for (i=0;i<60;i++){
    if (i%5!=0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(117,0);
      ctx.lineTo(120,0);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI/30);
  }
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";

  // write Hours

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#4D514E";
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate( -Math.PI/2 + hr*(Math.PI/6) + (Math.PI/360)*min + (Math.PI/21600)*sec )
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20,0);
  ctx.lineTo(80,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  // write Minutes
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate( -Math.PI/2 +(Math.PI/30)*min + (Math.PI/1800)*sec )
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-28,0);
  ctx.lineTo(110,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  // Write seconds
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2 +sec * Math.PI/30);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 6;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-30,0);
  ctx.lineTo(110,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
  ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#494545';
  ctx.arc(0,0,142,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.stroke();


  ctx.restore();
} init();
```

```css
canvas {
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="datetime" value="03:45:01">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script>



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2)` at the beginning of your `clock` function, you need to rotate the digits back. To do this you'd need to translate context to a digit coordinates first, and then rotate the context by `Math.PI/2`.

Replace this part of code in your for loop:

```
ctx.fillText(n, x, y);
ctx.rotate(theta );
```

with this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
ctx.fillText(n, 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```